# Partial width borders

Tags: html, css, border

How can I produce borders that don't stretch the whole width of a given box? E.g.:

[image]

Do I have to use a separate HTML element with a different width? Or can I achieve this entirely via CSS.

Comment: I think those particular elements are `<hr />`s with their `width` set.

Comment: Right, my question is whether I can achieve this effect without adding any additional HTML elements (`<hr>`s or otherwise)

Comment: what are your browser requirements/targets?

Comment: Everything except IE6 and Opera, I guess (though if there's some CSS3 solution that gives IE a useable but sub-par experience, that's probably ok too)

Comment: this is getting flagged because of the image content. Can you please substitute something without the objectionable language?

Comment: Done (though I feel like I just scribbled on the Mona Lisa's face!)

Answer (score 18):

You can always use a CSS :after statement:

```
<style>
div.hr-like:after {
    height:1px;
    background:#333;
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
    content:""
}
</style>

<div class="hr-like">
    foo
</div>
```

---

Added:  Here's an example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDy8W/)

Comment: Yes.  Here's the quirksmode page on it:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a background image to each partial div and place it along the bottom in the middle. Then the separator can be what you want and how long you want, like that pencil line you got there.

```
#content {
    background: transparent url('http://placekitten.com/200/10') no-repeat bottom center;
}
```

Sorry for the kittens...